# Why am I unable to add a depends_on block to a module with provider configuration?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

When writing examples for my Terraform module, I got the error:
"Module contains provider configuration"
"Providers cannot be configured within modules using count, for_each or depends_on."

I got this error when I tried to add a `depends_on` block to the module's declaration to avoid trying to run the module plan before the creation of the resource group needed to deploy the resources inside the module.

If I don't add the `depends_on` block it also breaks, because it can't find the declared resource group that should be created before the module runs to populate the required resource group data source.

I find it is at least uncomfortable to require the removal of the `providers` block or to remove all the data sources.

I couldn't find any details on this error, or on how to fix it.

[Specific line that raises this error inside Terraform's code.](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/6bed3008a5d993bd89b2dafa101ebcd9cbced5a0/configs/provider_validation.go#L103)

Comment: I'm not sure about `depends_on`, but I know that it *is* possible to use `for_each` in a module resource that contains a provider block. What version of Terraform are you using? Can you maybe provide some example code?

Comment: A module containing its own provider configurations is not compatible with the for_each, count, and depends_on arguments that were introduced in Terraform v0.13. Have you tried it with Terraform v0.15.1?

Comment: I'm using Terraform v0.15

Comment: This is what I got from the Terraform team, maybe you can help me understand why this is the way it is: 
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/28580#issuecomment-831263879

Answer (score 2):

From the error message, it sounds like there is a Provider conflict. This can occur when a module is called using a different provider to that declared in the parent.

Example

```
.
├── main.tf
├── outputs.tf
├── provider.tf
├── runtime.yaml
└── variables.tf
```

If in the above provider it declares the following:

```
provider "google" {
  project = var.gcp_project_id
  region  = var.gcp_region
  zone    = var.gcp_zone
}

provider "google-beta" {
  project = var.gcp_project_id
  region  = var.gcp_region
  zone    = var.gcp_zone
}
```

If you then reference a module, the expectation is the module references the above parent Provider configuration. If the module declares their own configuration and it differs from the above, Terraform will report an error.

To fix the issue you should respect the parent Provider. Remove the provider declaration from the module and then the dependency should then be compatible.

Also note when you update the providers - you will need to perform a `terraform init`. I removed the pre-existing Terraform hidden directories to ensure it correctly picks up the new settings.

Answer (score 1):

What you have probably looks similar to code below, right?

```
Root module (eg. terraform.tf):
---

... some code...

module "child_module" {
    count  = var.children_no
    source = "./modules/childmodule.tf"
  ...
}
```

and

```
Child module (childmodule.tf)
---

... some code  ...

provider "any_provider" {
    ...
}
```

So... the sad thing is... you can not do that. If module have any provider at all, you can not 'count' it. :/

That's basically what the error said. You either have to get your provider out of module or get out `count` from root module.